# Update a DynamicContent item of a dynamic module in Sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity

I am trying to update a DynamicContent Property of a module using the following:

```
    DynamicModuleManager dynamicModuleManager = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager();
        Type pollanswerType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Poll.Pollanswer");
        Guid pollanswerID = new Guid(answerID);


        // This is how we get the pollanswer item by ID
        DynamicContent pollanswerItem = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItem(pollanswerType, pollanswerID);
        pollanswerItem.SetValue("VoteCount", int.Parse(pollanswerItem.GetValue("VoteCount").ToString()) + 1);

        dynamicModuleManager.SaveChanges();
```

Basically getting the current Property value and incrementing it by 1
and calling SaveChanges()
the code runs without errors but it doesn't update the value when I check it from the Back End of Sitefinity.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be caused by the **pollanswerID** that you are passing.

If the **pollanswerID** is the id of the **live** version of the content item then the value wouldn't be set.

Make sure you set the field value to the of **master** version of the content type **not the live** one.

In case you don't know the id of the master version of the content type you can **get the master content item** by the id of the live version of the content type

```
var masterItem = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(pollanswerType).Where(dynItem => dynItem.Id == pollanswerItem.OriginalContentId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (masterItem != null)
            {
                masterItem.SetValue("VoteCount",   int.Parse(masterItem.GetValue("VoteCount").ToString()) + 5);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be always doing this

- Get Master
- Checkout Master
- Checkin Master
- Save Changes
- Publish changes – this will update live.

bookingItemLive is the live record

```
var bookingItemMaster = dynamicModuleManager.Lifecycle.Edit(bookingItemLive) as DynamicContent;

//Check out the master to get a temp version.
DynamicContent bookingItemTemp = dynamicModuleManager.Lifecycle.CheckOut(bookingItemMaster) as DynamicContent;

//Make the modifications to the temp version.
bookingItemTemp.SetValue("CleanerId", cleanerId);
bookingItemTemp.SetValue("SubCleanerId", subCleanerId);
bookingItemTemp.LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;

//Checkin the temp and get the updated master version.
//After the check in the temp version is deleted.
bookingItemMaster = dynamicModuleManager.Lifecycle.CheckIn(bookingItemTemp) as DynamicContent;

dynamicModuleManager.SaveChanges();

//Publish the item now 
ILifecycleDataItem publishedBookingItem = dynamicModuleManager.Lifecycle.Publish(bookingItemMaster);
bookingItemMaster.SetWorkflowStatus(dynamicModuleManager.Provider.ApplicationName, "Published");
```

Answer (score 0):

@Joseph Ghassan: You can follow below step.

Step 1: Get Live

```
var bookingItemLive= manager.GetDataItem(ModuleType, GuidId);
```

Step 2: Get Master

```
var bookingItemMaster = manager.Lifecycle.GetMaster(bookingItemLive) as DynamicContent;
```

Step 2: Checkout Master --> will be created a draft item( you will update data by draft)

```
if (bookingItemMaster == null)
{
   return new HttpResponseMessage
              {
                  Content = new JsonContent(new { Result = false })
              };
}

var bookingItemDraff = manager.Lifecycle.CheckOut(bookingItemMaster) as DynamicContent;

//Make the modifications to the temp version.

bookingItemDraff.SetValue("CleanerId", cleanerId);

bookingItemDraff.SetValue("SubCleanerId", subCleanerId);

bookingItemDraff.LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Step 3: Checkin Master

```
// Now we need to check in, so the changes apply
var checkInItem = manager.Lifecycle.CheckIn(bookingItemDraff);
```

Step 4: Publish changes

```
manager.Lifecycle.Publish(checkInItem);
```

Step 5: Save Changes - this will save to Database and update live.

```
bookingItemDraff.SetWorkflowStatus(manager.Provider.ApplicationName, CustomFieldName.PublishedStatus);
manager.SaveChanges();
```